# How to declare parameters for Require.js modules that are declaring a window variable

Tags: javascript, requirejs

How do I properly reference modules in the parameters list of Require.js that don't export a variable, since they are bound to the window object? I'm using 'undefined' right now, however, jshint is telling me "'undefined' is already defined.", since two parameters are called 'undefined'.

```
require(["jquery", "html5shiv", "plugins", "backbone"], function ($, undefined, undefined, backbone) {

   // Your code here

});
```

Comment: try placing such dependencies last and omit their export substitutes: require(["jquery", "backbone", other deps], function($, Backbone) { /* module code */ }). Not sure if it works, you gotta try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For dependencies that do not actually expose something (e.g. side-effect only) I place them last as lexeme says in the comment:

```
require(["realDependency1", "realDependency2", "sideEffectDependency"],
    function(realDependency1, realDependency2) {
        ...
    }
);
```

If the dependency actually provides something, but not through RequireJS's mechanism, you can [shim](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim) it:

```
require.config({
    ...
    shim: {
        ...
        "ng": {
            exports: "angular"
        },
        ...
    }
});
```

This actually says that whenever I require `"ng"` (e.g. `define(["ng"],...)`), the global variable `angular` (a.k.a. `window.angular`) will be returned.